# how to set video width to 100% up to some max value in iframe with div?

Tags: html, css, iframe

My first time embedding a youtube video anywhere, and I'm trying to optimize the video's size for both desktop and mobile.

I want to embed the video with a MAX width of 940 px and MAX height of 630 px, and otherwise the video should be as large as the screen allows. Meaning, mobile devices should have a width of 100% and desktop browsers should have 100% up to the max limits.

Is this possible?

Here's my code so far:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">

   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx?rel=0" 
       frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

I've tried various combinations of width, height, max-width, and max-height, but haven't got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a container, and use the good old `padding-bottom` trick. This way you can make it retain the aspect ratio and control the size of the container instead of the actual embedded thing. The container can be handled like any other normal `div`.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/foykobm5/1/

HTML

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #eee;
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Roope, how did you compute the 56.25% `padding-bottom` number? And, can I use `text-align:center` for `div` style to center the video?

Comment: @user46688 56.25% is for the normal aspect ratio 16:9 since 9 by 16 is 0.5625.

Comment: OK, so if I were using a 16:10 ratio, then I'd replace that accordingly using 10/16...

Comment: @user46688 Yes. For centering, I would use `margin: 0 auto;` on the video container. As an example, I made the main container a bit wider so that you can see that the video is centered in that container even if the outside container is wider than the video.

Comment: @user46688 Anyway, if that solved your problem, please remember to accept the answer. If not, ask more questions :)